# How to write multiple conditions in Makefile.am with "else if"

Tags: automake

I want to compile my project with autoconf/automake. There are 2 conditions defined in my configure.ac

```
AM_CONDITIONAL(HAVE_CLIENT, test $enable-client -eq 1)
AM_CONDITIONAL(HAVE_SERVER, test $enable-server -eq 1)
```

I want to separate _LIBS from these 2 conditions in Makefile.am

```
if HAVE_CLIENT

libtest_LIBS = \

    $(top_builddir)/libclient.la

else if HAVE_SERVER

libtest_LIBS = \

    $(top_builddir)/libserver.la

else

libtest_LIBS = 

endif
```

but `else if HAVE_SERVER` does NOT work.

How to write 'else if' in makefile.am?

Answer (score 172):

ptomato's code can also be written in a cleaner manner like:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_CPU),x86)
  TARGET_CPU_IS_X86 := 1
else ifeq ($(TARGET_CPU),x86_64)
  TARGET_CPU_IS_X86 := 1
else
  TARGET_CPU_IS_X86 := 0
endif
```

Comment: but here you need to put two `endif` together at the same level of indentation, which altogether wouldn't look good either

Comment: @amc in the example above a single `endif` is enough, which I've just added.  The problem with the indentation is given in all cases (when using a bigger/nested `else` block).

Comment: Continuing in the spirit of “as it’s the top result on google” :) if you’re trying to replicate this, make sure you don’t forget the space before the parenthesis in `else ifeq (…)`. `make` gets confused if it’s missing and will end the conditional early.

Comment: You cannot use this syntax in Makefile.am

Comment: This fails with GNU Make 3.80. Error messages are, *`Extraneous text after 'else' directive.`*.

Answer (score 17):

I would accept ldav1s' answer if I were you, but I just want to point out that 'else if' can be written in terms of 'else's and 'if's in any language:

```
if HAVE_CLIENT
  libtest_LIBS = $(top_builddir)/libclient.la
else
  if HAVE_SERVER
    libtest_LIBS = $(top_builddir)/libserver.la
  else
    libtest_LIBS = 
  endif
endif
```

(The indentation is for clarity. **Don't indent the lines, they won't work.**)

Comment: I have tried this one, but failed. Is it possible Makefile.am doesn't support recursive if conditions.

Comment: Did you remove the indentation? All those statements are supposed to start in column 1.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remove the indentation, I'll try it.

Comment: I have just tried that, and it works great. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You can use indentation in line 2, 5 and 7. (only with tabs not with spaces)
Only the if, else and endif statements do not allow indentation.

Answer (score 17):

```
ifeq ($(CHIPSET),8960)
   BLD_ENV_BUILD_ID="8960"
else ifeq ($(CHIPSET),8930)
   BLD_ENV_BUILD_ID="8930"
else ifeq ($(CHIPSET),8064)
   BLD_ENV_BUILD_ID="8064"
else ifeq ($(CHIPSET), 9x15)
   BLD_ENV_BUILD_ID="9615"
else
   BLD_ENV_BUILD_ID=
endif
```

Comment: This fails with GNU Make 3.80. Error messages are, *`Extraneous text after 'else' directive`*.

Comment: I like this style and this syntax works as written in the version of gnu make I am using.
Question:  Can this syntax work if the conditional test is for something different on each 'else ifeq' ???
For example could I do this:
ifeq ($chipset),1860)
   BLD_ENV_BUILD_ID="8960"
else ifeq ($hostname, "JohnsLaptop")
    BLD_ENV_BUILD_ID="9615"
else
    BILD_ENV_BUILD_ID=
endif

Answer (score 7):

```
ifdef $(HAVE_CLIENT)
libtest_LIBS = \
    $(top_builddir)/libclient.la
else
ifdef $(HAVE_SERVER)
libtest_LIBS = \
    $(top_builddir)/libserver.la
else
libtest_LIBS = 
endif
endif
```

NOTE: DO NOT indent the if then it don't work!

Answer (score 6):

As you've discovered, you can't do that. You can do:

```
libtest_LIBS =
```

...

```
if HAVE_CLIENT
libtest_LIBS += libclient.la
endif

if HAVE_SERVER
libtest_LIBS += libserver.la
endif
```

Comment: Yes, this is good. Thanks for your reply, but actually I have 3 conditions. CLIENT, SERVER, non-CLIENT-non-SERVER. I don't know how to add the 3rd condition in my code.

Comment: There's actually 4 conditions wrt AM_CONDITIONAL: !CLIENT && !SERVER, !CLIENT && SERVER, CLIENT && SERVER, CLIENT && !SERVER.  This answer will work with all these conditions.  For the "3rd condition" (!CLIENT && !SERVER) libtest_LIBS is set to the value you wanted in the 'else if'.