# Why doesn't Make allow indented "if" statements?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

It's a constant thorn in my side when trying to read a makefile with nested logic, that *Make* does not allow indented *if* statements. Why is this, and is there a good way to work around this limitation, and still have readable makefiles?

**Update**: I now realise that this question is based on a false premise, but I believe that leaving it here may be valuable to anyone who makes the same mistake that I did.

Comment: Indented condiitionals are supported. Maybe you should illustrate with a [mcve] why you think it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hmm. An example would be impossible as the code I'm working on is massive, proprietary and not really something I understand. My supposition about indented conditionals comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8062124/10406360

Comment: So you didn't even try?

Comment: I can't post proprietary code; I'd lose my job! However, I did try your solution and it failed. Please see my comment below your answer.

Comment: That's why the help page says [mcve]. Nobody has asked you to copy the whole shebang...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to the help of others, I now realize that my question is posed on a false premise. Makefiles absolutely *do* allow for indented if statements, or rather indented conditionals to be more precise. What they don't allow for - at least out of the box - are *tabbed* conditionals. This is because, by default, *Make* interprets *tabs* as especially meaningful characters. Almost any line beginning with a tab character is interpreted to be part of a [recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html#Recipe-Syntax). Therefore, any line that is *not* intended to be part of a recipe - such as conditionals - should *not* begin with a tab.

As far as answering the part of my question that asked *why* they chose to use the tab character in this way, I haven't found an answer. Perhaps the designers intended for conditionals to be used sparingly.

As for workarounds, here I will attempt to describe a couple.

The first solution is a terrible pain if you don't have an editor that shows *whitespace* characters, but if you do, the simplest thing to do might be to just add some *spaces* to indent your non recipe code. This is a rather hackish workaround though and probably ill advised.

Another solution (courtesy of @Stefan Becker) is to set the [special variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html), `.RECIPEPREFIX` to a character other than tab. Here's an example of what I tried:

```
.RECIPEPREFIX := >
# Now, all recipes will begin with the > character rather than a tab.

things = something another_thing something_else nothing
nothing = true

something: another_thing something_else
# See how each line of a recipe now begins with >.
# You can see I also added a tab after the >. 
# These tabs doesn't mean anything to Make; it's just for readability.
>   $(info Making $@.)
>   @touch $@

another_thing:
>   $(info Making $@.)
    # See also how lines like comments can be tabbed, 
    # but no longer add anything meaningful to recipes.
>   @touch $@

something_else:
>   $(info Making $@.)
>   @touch $@
    # And just to prove the situation with conditionals is resolved...
    # See how the @touch command begins with the new RECIPEPREFIX 
    # but the conditionals don't.
    ifeq ($(nothing),true)
>       $(info Also making nothing, because nothing is true.)
>       @touch nothing
    endif

.PHONY: everything_clean
everything_clean:
>   $(info Cleaning up everything.)
>   rm -f $(things)
```

One thing worth remembering is that recipe lines must *begin* with the new `RECIPEPREFIX`. That is to say, that something like this *won't* work:

```
something: another_thing something_else
# Remember that the RECIPEPREFIX must come first. 
# Indenting your recipe lines first and then using the RECIPEPRIFX will not work.
    >$(info Making $@.)
    >@touch $@
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are under the impression that indented conditionals aren't supported. They do seem to work fine when I use them in the following example:

```makefile
.PHONY: all
all:

CONFIGS :=

ifeq ($(CONFIG1),1)
  $(info CONFIG1 selected)

  CONFIGS += config1
  all: config1

  config1:
    @echo $@


  ifeq ($(CONFIG2),1)
    $(info CONFIG2 selected)

    CONFIGS += config2
    all: config2

    config2:
    @echo $@

  else
    $(info CONFIG2 not selected)
  endif
else
  $(info CONFIG1 NOT selected)
endif

all:
    @echo "all: $(CONFIGS)"
```

**NOTE**: the TABS in my example will probably not survive copy & paste. So you'll have to re-enter them for the recipes.

Test run:

```
$ make
CONFIG1 NOT selected
all:

$ make CONFIG1=1
CONFIG1 selected
CONFIG2 not selected
config1
all:  config1

$ make CONFIG1=1 CONFIG2=1
CONFIG1 selected
CONFIG2 selected
config1
config2
all:  config1 config2
```

---

#### But...

There is one case where indentation can lead to problems. To quote the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction):

> A recipe is an action that `make` carries out. A recipe may have more than one command, either on the same line or each on its own line. **Please note:** you need to put a tab character at the beginning of every recipe line! This is an obscurity that catches the unwary.

As GNU make takes *all TAB indented lines* after a rule to be part of the recipe for the rule the following will fail for `make CONFIG1=1`:

```makefile
.PHONY: all
all:

CONFIGS :=

config1:
# TAB in the following line
    @echo $@

# the following lines are indented with TABs
    ifeq ($(CONFIG1),1)
    CONFIGS += config1
    test1:
        @echo $@
    endif

ifeq ($(CONFIG1),1)
all: config1
endif

all:
# TAB in the following line
    @echo "all: $(CONFIGS)"
```

```
$ make CONFIG1=1
config1
ifeq (1,1)
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `1,1'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq (1,1)'
make: *** [Makefile:9: config1] Error 1
```

#### Solution

1. organize the makefile to have conditionals first, then rules, i.e. no TAB indentation after rules anymore except for recipes, or
2. always make sure to use SPACEs for conditional, variable assignment and rule lines.
3. set `.RECIPEPREFIX` to a *non-whitespace* character, e.g. `>` and use that to indicate recipe lines.<sup>1</sup>

Unless you have an editor which shows the difference between TABs and SPACEs, alternative 2 will probably drive you insane. I would suggest alternative 1 instead...

The following works for `make CONFIG2=1`:

```makefile
.PHONY: all
all:

CONFIGS :=

config2:
# TAB in the following line
    @echo $@

# the following lines are indented with SPACES
    ifeq ($(CONFIG2),1)
    CONFIGS += config2
    test2:
# 2 TABs in the following line
        @echo $@
    endif

ifeq ($(CONFIG2),1)
all: config2
endif

all:
# TAB in the following line
    @echo "all: $(CONFIGS)"
```

```
$ make CONFIG2=1
config2
all:  config2
```

---

<sup>1</sup> you might be tempted to set [`.RECIPEPREFIX`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction) to SPACE like this:

```makefile
_empty        :=
_space        := $(_empty) $(_empty)
.RECIPEPREFIX := $(_space)
```

and then switch your editor to use only SPACEs. But that makes things worse, i.e. now `make` can't distinguish between normal and recipe indentation. If you try this with the above example you will note that it now fails for any invocation that enables one of the indented rules.

Comment: D:\tony>make
Makefile:29: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer already: the TABs from my example won't survive copy & paste. You need to replace the leading spaces in front of the recipes in lines 13, 23 & 33 with TABs. Just to be sure `make --version` says `GNU Make 4.2.1`.

Comment: I have updated my answer with one case where indentation can lead to problems and a solution for it.

Comment: I replaced the spaces with tabs as I think they are in your example, though I guess I can't be sure I've added the right number of tabs in the right locations. My make version is 3.82.90, which seems incredibly out of date by comparison, but I'm constrained to using that version by policy. Interestingly, the error I get with your example is the same as the one that initially brought me here. Considering the liklihood that either my make version or my ability to count tabs properly is the issue, and seeing as the premise of my question seems to be false, I should probably delete the question.

Comment: As you seem to be using Windows I would strongly suggest to update to version 4.x. In the updated section I tried to indicate the position of the TABs in the comments.

Comment: I replaced 4 SPACEs with 2 SPACEs in the last example so that the formatting on the web page looks the same as I see it in my editor (I uses TAB == 8 spaces, SO == 4 spaces).

Comment: Stefan. After reading points 1 and 2 of your **Solution,** I finally understand now how my entire question is posed upon a false supposition. I had been using the tab character for _all_ of my indentation, without realizing that tabs are reserved for recipes only. Thus, I guess my question would have been valid if I had asked, "why doesn't make allow **tabbed** _if_ statements, but as it stands, the question is not valid. I'm sorry for any confusion I have caused.

Comment: @LongTP5 no problem. I just realized that there is one more thing I forgot to mention, updated my answer accordingly. Can you please accept the answer, so that your question appears as closed?